# error with cwac-endless, when extending EndlessAdapter

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

i added the jar file in build path, but whenever i'm extending EndlessAdapter i got an error saying "The type com.commonsware.cwac.adapter.AdapterWrapper cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless):

> This project relies upon the [CWAC AdapterWrapper](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-adapter/tree/master) project. A copy of compatible JARs can be found in the `libs/` directory of the project, though you are welcome to try newer ones, or ones that you have patched yourself.

Comment: EDIT: i am using this jar file: https://github.com/downloads/commonsguy/cwac-endless/CWAC-EndlessAdapter.jar

Comment: @Joe: You *also* need the JAR file that I mention in my answer. That's why it is listed in the documentation under the large, bold-face heading of "Dependencies".